# even though a person has not contributed in github why is he shown under contributors

Tags: git, github

[image: why is it showing like this]

Even though on clicking the contributors

[image: contributors].

how should a remove a contributor name from the contributors list who did not do any contribution (over here cadris)

[image: the commit history]

Comment: If the project is public, please link to it - otherwise please ask GitHub support.